# why the el-input could not input anything in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript

Now I am writing a Google Chrome Extension that using vue el-input to input the username and password, when input username and password, store the username and password into storage.the code like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="title">Login</div>
        <div class="setting-name">username：</div>
        <div class="setting-input">
            <el-input @change="saveConfig" placeholder="please input username" ></el-input>
        </div>
        <div class="setting-name">password：</div>
        <div class="setting-input">
            <el-input @change="saveConfig" placeholder="please input password"></el-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

but when I type the username and password in the UI, the el-input did not show what I am inputting. It means could not input anything. what should I do to fix it? The vue version is:

```
"vue": "2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "15.9.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.12",
```

I have tried to forceUpdate like this:

```
  <el-input @change="saveConfig" placeholder="please input username" @input="onInput()"></el-input>


 methods: {
        onInput(){
            this.$forceUpdate();
        },
}
```

still not work. This is my full code:

```
<template>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="title">登录</div>
        <div class="setting-name">用户名：</div>
        <div class="setting-input">
            <el-input @change="saveConfig" placeholder="请输入你的用户名" @input="onInput()"></el-input>
        </div>
        <div class="setting-name">密码：</div>
        <div class="setting-input">
            <el-input @change="saveConfig" placeholder="请输入你的密码"></el-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Login',
    data: () => ({
        loading: true,
        defaultConfig,
        config: defaultConfig,
        time: '',
        leftTime: '',
        second: 0,
        refreshDisabled: false,
        isChrome: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') !== -1,
        
    }),
    methods: {
        onInput(){
            this.$forceUpdate();
        },
        saveConfig() {
            saveConfig(this.config, () => {
                this.$message({
                    message: '保存成功',
                    type: 'success'
                });
            });
        },
        toHotkey() {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: 'chrome://extensions/shortcuts'
            });
        },
        refreshRu() {
            this.refreshDisabled = true;
            refreshRules(() => {
                this.second = 0;
                this.time = secondToTime(this.second);
                this.leftTime = secondToTime(this.config.refreshTimeout - this.second);
                this.refreshDisabled = false;
            });
        },
        refreshTime() {
            getRulesDate((date) => {
                this.second = (+new Date - +date) / 1000;
                this.time = secondToTime(this.second);
                this.leftTime = secondToTime(this.config.refreshTimeout - this.second);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.refreshTime();
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to console.log the value of the field's input in the saveConfig method?

Comment: I tried, seems did not trigger the onchange event and invoke saveConfig method.@ElonZito